# Does OpenTest support automated tests on a headless browser?

Tags: automated-tests, browser-automation, opentest

Is it possible to execute OpenTest scripts on a headless instance?

My actor file configuration is done as below, but the browser is called as default. Should that be enough to run the latest Chrome version on headless mode?

```
...
selenium:
    # seleniumServerUrl: http://127.0.0.1:9515
    desiredCapabilities:
        browserName: chrome
        chromeOptions:
            args: [ --headless ]
    chromeDriverExePath: C:/opentest/drivers/chromedriver.exe
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

OpenTest supports sending command line arguments to the Selenium driver(s) using parameters like `chromeDriverExeArgs`, `firefoxDriverExeArgs`, etc. Here's how you can set the `headless` argument in the `actor.yaml` file and configure the browser window size:

```
...
selenium:
    desiredCapabilities:
        browserName: chrome
    chromeDriverExePath: C:/opentest/drivers/chromedriver.exe
    chromeDriverExeArgs: [ headless ]
    resolution: 1920x1080
...
```

Resolution can also be changed dynamically from the test by using the [SetBrowserAspect](https://getopentest.org/reference/selenium-keywords.html#setbrowseraspect) keyword.